# How can I replace a window with html as well as change the location at the same time so assets in the html would load correctly?

Tags: javascript, url, query-string, html

Assuming I have some HTML with predefined assets using relative paths, how would I load that HTML in the current page and change the window location to the correct URL at the same time so that the page and all its assets load correctly.

Currently if I use:

```
const w = window.open()
w.document.write("<html><body><p>help</p></body></html>")
w.location.replace("http://baseUrl.com")
```

The page then renders the html and then reloads when the location is replaced, rendering the `document.write` useless.

Is there a way to do both at the same time so that the url loads as well as the html?

If I do

```
const w = window.open()
w.location.replace("http://baseUrl.com")
w.document.write("<html><body><p>help</p></body></html>")
```

The third line doesnt run because I lose access to the `w` variable when the location is replaced.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use a query string in the `window.replace` like so:

```
const w = window.open();
window.location.replace("http://baseUrl.com?data=" + encodeUriComponent("<html><body><p>help</p></body></html>"));
```

Then in the file at `baseUrl.com`:

```
var data = decodeUriComponent(window.location.href).split("?")[1];
document.write(data);
```

What this does is it passes an encoded URI query string into the URL (`?data=<html><body><p>help</p></body></html>`), then receives and decodes it, takes the bit at the end (the HTML) and writes it to the document. Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is i dont own the file at `baseUrl.com` I get the contents from a `POST` request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are better ways instead of relative url's for your target, but you may use `<base href='...'>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML + "<base href='http://baseUrl.com/' />";
</script>
```

The base tag usually needs a trailing '/' at its end.

example:

```
<base href="http://localhost/mywebsite/" />
```

Then all of the URLs in your HTML can just be this:

```
<img src="images/example.png" />
<a href="/images/example.png">Link To Image</a>
```

Comment: Im thinking of doing something like this...possibly do a replace of the html string like so:
`htmlString.replace("<head>", "<head><base href='baseUrl.com'>")`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this (using setInterval to detect opened window loaded, then write your help information , url must be same domain):

```
var w = window.open("http://baseUrl.com")
        var writeAsserts = function () 
        {
            if (w.document.body.childNodes.length > 0) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                var div = w.document.createElement("div")
                div.innerHTML = "<span>help</span>";
                w.document.body.appendChild(div)
            }
        }
        var interval = setInterval(writeAsserts,10)
```

Comment: what do you mean url must be same domain? `baseUrl.com` and my webapp will be on different domains. Thank you for the answer though!

Comment: you can not  modify page content across domain for security reason. In your situation, you probably add a wrapper page in your web(the same domain) to show the file  from baseUrl.com. In your wrapper page , split the page  body to two parts , one to show you help information , another use i.e. iframe to show file from baseUrl.com , then you can probably  modify your help information area .